# Is it possible to use VPN only for virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn

I want to use a VPN only for some applications, if I use a virtual machine with a VPN configured on it, my entire pc will use that VPN or only my virtual machine will use that VPN?

Another question.  Is it possible to restrict my VPN for only several applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to configure VPN only in a virtual container. In this case the host will not be using VPN while the virtual container does.